# Convert from Bitmap to MIplImage or IplImage c#

Tags: opencv, bitmap, emgucv, iplimage

I have an algorithm in created in c++ to make background subtraction, and i want to call it from c# with an argument "IplImage" using dll(extern). The problem that i acquire the camera stream in c# and i have the frame as image (bitmap).

How could i convert the bitmap to IplImage to send it in c++ and vice versa to retrieve the frame treated?

Many thanks.

Comment: show some code for detail help

Comment: check this out http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/sending-Bitmap-class-argument-to-C-function-and-using-it-for-IplImage-td5599929.html

Answer (score 0):

Using Emgucv, you can try

```
Bitmap bitmap = ....
Emgu.CV.Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmap);
Emgu.CV.Structure.MIplImage = img.MIplImage;
```

to send it in C++ method you can pass it as [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) object

```
IntPtr r = IntPtr.Zero;
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(img, r, false);

// call your c++ method 
...
```

also see detail about [`Marshal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx)